# Fastest way to copy table contet from one server to another

Tags: bcp, sap-ase

Im looking for fastest way to copy some tables from one sybase server (ase 12.5) to another. Currently im using bcp tool but it takes time to create proper bcp.fmt file.

Tables have the same structure. There is about 25K rows in every table. I have to copy about 40 tables.
I tryed to use -c parameter for bcp but I get errors while importing:

```
CSLIB Message:  - L0/O0/S0/N24/1/0:
cs_convert: cslib user api layer: common library error: The conversion/operation
 was stopped due to a syntax error in the source field.
```

My standard bcp in/out commands:

```
bcp.exe SPEPL..VSoftSent out VSoftSent.csv -U%user% -P%pass% -S%srv% -c
bcp.exe SPEPL..VSoftSent in VSoftSent.csv -U%user2% -P%pass2% -S%srv2% -e import.err -c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are copying from different servers, BCP is the way to go!

If it was in the same server would be different.

Comment: Yes, im sure bcp is right tool, but bcp in creates conversaition errors on file just bcp outed. Servers seems to have same configuration. I think that the problem is in datetime formating. Are there any tricks to force bcp to use custom formating in file?

Comment: @JarekBielicki I made a brief search and I didn't found any :( but I really don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying it's from 1 Sybase ASE host to another Sybase ASE host?

If you don't want to mess with BCP or I/O on the file system, you could create a CIS proxy table in your destination database that references either a stored procedure with a select statement or a physical table in your source database.

Then you could just
insert into destinationtable (col1, col2...)
select
  col1, col2...
from proxytablename

CIS proxy is fairly resource intensive, so I'd be very careful about how much work you're doing here.